# React vs Angular что выбрать для SPA?

Tags: reactjs, архитектура, spa, angular5

Знаю, что тема изучена вдоль и поперек, но все же, как вы считаете, какие есть плюсы у `angular` или `react` для разработки `SPA`?

Берем в расчет, то что команда может писать и на одном и на другом.

Задачи:

1. Разработать приложение в короткие сроки.
2. Должно работать, как на desktop так и на мобильных устройствах.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от приложения. Что именно хотите разработать?

Лучше то что Ваши разработчики знают на более высоком уровне и где есть больше опыта, от этого зависит скорость.

Фреймворки всего лишь инструмент.